# Jconsole Cassandra Remote connection

Tags: java, cassandra, cassandra-3.0, jconsole

I am connecting remote cassandra cluster through jconsole. I set the below properties in cassandra-env.sh

```
JMX_PORT="7199"
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=$JMX_PORT"
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=true"
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false"
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=x.x.x.x"
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote"
```

I am getting this error when i debug through **jconsole -debug x.x.x.x:7199**

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Expecting a javax.rmi.ssl.SslRMIClientSocketFactory RMI client socket factory in stub!
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.checkStub(RMIConnector.java:1901)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.connect(RMIConnector.java:295)
    at sun.tools.jconsole.ProxyClient.tryConnect(ProxyClient.java:355)
    at sun.tools.jconsole.ProxyClient.connect(ProxyClient.java:313)
    at sun.tools.jconsole.VMPanel$2.run(VMPanel.java:294)
```

please somebody help me out from this issue.

Thanks & Regards
pavs

Comment: Did you create jmxremote.access and jmxremote.password files?

Comment: Yup. I created but i am still getting the same error.